# Setting environment variables from Text File

Tags: bash, shell, export, environment-variables, ksh

I am trying to export some path names based on text in a text file however I am having some trouble,

```
file="config.txt"

while read line
do
    LINE= "$line"
    echo "$line"

done <"$file"
export LINE
```

I have tried using the above code but it does not save the String in config.txt to LINE. Any suggestions would be great!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to eliminate the spaces around the assignment operator:

```
LINE="$line"
```

Also, the script will only save the *last* line from your file into the variable. All previous lines will be overwritten as the code loops.